# ERROR: bad URI when sending data as JSON with GET method to a Rails resource

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, rest, webrick

Hello I'm performing a GET request on a RESTful Rails resource, like so:

```
function getGroups(category) { 

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/groups.json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"access_token":"569669d8df0456", "category":category }),
    success: function(data) {alert(data)},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
  });

});

getGroups("own_groups");
```

The problem is that Webrick server errors out like this:

> ERROR bad URI
>   `/groups.json?{%22access_token%22:%22569669d8df0456%22,%22category%22:%22own_groups%22}'.

It must be something related with how the JSON data is parsed, because I am having no problems with another GET request WITHOUT JSON data, and a POST request WITH JSON data...

---

**Update: adding code for POST request (where JSON.stringify is required)**

```
function addGroup(name, description) {
  $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'http://localhost:3000/groups.json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"access_token":"569669d8df0456", "group_name":name, "group_description":description}),
    success: function(data) { alert("ok")},
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
  });
};

addGroup("nice group", "full of people");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `JSON.stringify`. Simply put:

```
data: {"access_token":"569669d8df0456", "category":category },
```

Moreover, you do not need to specify complete url `http://localhost:3000/groups.json`, it can be just simply `groups.json`

Comment: Wow, that was fast and right to the point. Oh it's still you :) Thanks! Accepting soon (need to wait 10 mins) ;).

Comment: I used JSON.stringify because in the POST method I had to use it, and the data is almost the same... So... could you think of why I'm seeing this different behaviour?

Comment: Why do you need to use it? Request header data format does not differ for GET and POST methods.

Comment: It was erroring out if I did not use it in POST. I will give you more details as soon as I'll get again on that part of code